# Firefox localStorage database (data.sqlite) – how to read "value" column binary (blob) data?

Tags: sqlite, firefox, local-storage, binary-data

I lost my save with significant hours of progress in a browser game, and I wanted to inspect if the database file would still have the (potentially corrupt, but perhaps resquable) data. I killed firefox and took a copy of the relevant database file located in my case at `/home/fdagpigj/.mozilla/firefox/45otyetp.default/storage/default/https+++v6p9d9t4.ssl.hwcdn.net^partitionKey=%28https%2Citch.io%29/ls/data.sqlite`, which I was able to locate after some effort with the command `find . -type f -exec bash -c 'grep -q "Villager" < <(head "$1") && printf '%s\n' "$1"' _ {} \;`

[image: screenshot showing database columns "key" and "value" with values 'VillagerKingsSave' and BLOB respectively]

Above is a screenshot of the file in an sqlite db browser. I was able to extract the binary data out of the value column and write it to a new binary file, but I'm stumped for the next step – how do I actually open this binary file? What format does Firefox store it in? I doubt it's the game storing binary data into localStorage as I'm able to view it (a newer autosave of the game anyway) in the debug console storage tab just fine (it's just base64 encoded json there).

No program recognises the binary data and if I view it as ascii text it's just garble.

Comment: There is some [notes here](https://dfir.blog/deciphering-browser-hieroglyphics-localstorage/) for binary storage. I used the linked [CyberChef](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/) to view an example. I still need to find compression method for some other JSON arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The values ​​in the value column in lines where compression_type is set to "1" are compressed using the snappy algorithm.

There are libs for some programming languages ​​that handle this compression, such as: flow-php/snappy for PHP and https://github.com/golang/snappy for go.